# How to improve the following SQL select date in RDB

Tags: sql, datetime, oracle-rdb

I'm working on a .Net WinForms appliation that is connecting to a legacy RDB database...

Some of the fields for dates are stored as integers (imagine 2010-01-04 was the integer 20100104)

In the .Net world, I'd much rather work with datetime objects and I've been able to convert the integer into a date, just that it looks so ugly, takes up lots of lines, is prone to errors and I'm wondering if anyone would be able to improve it...Thanks heaps!

Note - I cannot edit the database so creating any form of "function" is out of the question...

Here's my current way of selecting the integer as a datetime:

```
select
CAST(
SUBSTRING(DATE_COL AS VARCHAR(8)) FROM 1 FOR 4) ||
'-' ||
SUBSTRING(CAST(DATE_COL) AS VARCHAR(8)) FROM 5 FOR 2) ||
'-' ||
SUBSTRING(CAST(DATE_COL) AS VARCHAR(8)) FROM 7 FOR 2) ||
' 00:00:00'
AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE_COL
from MY_TABLE
where ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I had to mess with Rdb.  I seem to recall that there was a way to convert to a TIMESTAMP datatype by doing something like

```
CAST('YYYYMMDDHHMMSSTT' AS TIMESTAMP)
```

WHERE 'YYYYMMDDHHNNSSTT' was a character string in year-month-day-hour-min-sec-fraction format.  You may need to use DATE ANSI here instead of TIMESTAMP - like I say, it's been a while.  Regardless, the following might work:

```
SELECT CAST((CAST(DATE_COL AS CHAR(8)) || '00000000') AS TIMESTAMP)...
```

which is still ugly but is perhaps better than all the substringing.  Anyways, play with it a bit and I'm sure you'll get it.

Comment: Ended up using a very similar solution to yours which was CAST(CAST(DATE_COL AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE VMS)

Comment: Ah-ha!  DATE VMS!  I knew it was *something* like that!  :-)  Glad to help spark your thinking.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use the TO_DATE after you've cast the `date_col` to a string:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date_col), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

...or 'YYYYDDMM' for the date format.

References:

- [TO_DATE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)
- [TO_CHAR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)

Comment: OMG Ponies, is Oracle RDB 7 the same as the Oracle of now? I thought they were different...

Comment: Just thought i'd add that your solution appears to be working except that it is forcing me to enter extra parameters (wants 3 for each), but I think this is related to the environment, not your solution...e.g. TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date_col,'00000000','NLS...'),'YYYYMMDD','NLS...') even though they are meant to be optional

Comment: Ok...I'm fairly certain that Oracle X is different to RDB...which was bought by Oracle...

Comment: I'd never heard of RDB before.  When I googled RDB 7, I thought it was pre-8i.  Luckily the syntax is supported, even if the parameters are non-optional in RDB 7.

Comment: Rdb was originally a DEC (Digital Equipment Corp) product, purchased by Oracle to get hold of some technology - I believe it was the cost-based optimizer, which Rdb had before Oracle's flagship product.  Used it for many years - good product, but tools were limited.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use LINQ library? It is very nice and powerful.

What are the typical queries that you are running (high-level pseudocode please).

Comment: the point is, poster has to get it converted before doing anything else with it. LINQ isn't the answer to everything!

Comment: Agreed with Mitch, I just want the .net code (therefore linq or whatever) to think it is already dealing with a date field